# manejo de archivos en swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Estoy empezando con este lenguaje y en este ejercicio en particular quiero usar el archivo Utilities.swift en la carpeta FMDB en un archivo CategoriasViewController.swift en la carpeta Controllers.

Las carpetas están creadas de manera "física", es decir se han creado dentro de la carpeta principal del proyecto, gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que lo solucionaríamos con un import o algo así pero no encuentro la sintaxis correcta

Answer (score 1):

El primer paso que debes hacer es que los archivos estén referenciados en tu proyecto. Al aparecer en rojo, quiere decir que ha encontrado los archivos pero no están referenciados en el proyecto (probablemente porque los hayas añadido sin referencias o porque los hayas añadido desde el Finder).

Para ello: Botón derecho en la carpeta donde se quiere agregar el archivo -> Agregar Archivos a "MyProject"

Una vez los tengas agregados podrás acceder a ellos desde código en el ViewController.

Para lectura de archivos te recomiendo este código extraído de una respuesta de StackOverflow (en inglés)

Swift 3.0

```
let file = "file.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

let text = "some text" //just a text

if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

    let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

    //writing
    do {
        try text.write(to: path, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}

    //reading
    do {
        let text2 = try String(contentsOf: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```

Para más info:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24098149/6203030

Answer (score -1):

No has intentado utilizar el framework de fmdb con ayuda de cocoapods??

```
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/README.markdown
```

Y para las utilerias trata de eliminar primero las referencias y luego trata de arrastrar los archivos al Xcode en la carpeta donde quieres que queden ubicados